# Editing JSON file at multiple positions without rewriting complete file

Tags: javascript, json, file

I have a JSON file that contains lots of nodes. Each node has a unique id. The following is an example skeleton structure of the JSON file.

```
{
    "node1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "student",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Ram",
            "lastname": "Kumar",
            "age": "20"
        }
    },
    "node2": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Teacher",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Ram",
            "subject": "Computers"
        }
}
```

Now, this was just sample data. Suppose, I have to find node 2, provided I have the position of the node in the file. That is it's beginning and the end. I create a read stream from the start position and the end position of the file to get the object within the complete JSON object in the file. Now, using JSON.parse function I am able to create an object within the program after parsing it.

But, now I use a writestream to make the changes in the object at the required positions after computing them.

For example, I have to edit the subject property of the teacher, and the main rule is I cannot completely write the object again. Rather, create a writestream at the position where there is subject property and just edit that value.

So, the question is how to do so? And that to with multiple positions to edit, that is editing multiple properties, without rewriting them all.

> I know I might face an issue if I use multi-threading for this to simultaneously edit the multiple properties at once, but I need a work around that too.

Comment: What you want can be achieved with a database, it's not possible using files.

Comment: I think you are going to need to bend your rules to accomplish this.  As mentioned above this is a problem databases solve.

Comment: That's what I am working on, trying to build something like my own database.